# Return 2 arrays from array based on sign

Tags: javascript, arrays, sign

I'm looking to be able to return 2 arrays from an initial array, all the same size of course. One would replace all of the negative numbers with 0 and retain the positives, the other would replace all the positives with zero and retain the absolute value (pos) of the negative numbers.

For instance, if [2,-4,5,7], then I'd like to be able to get [2,0,5,7] and [0,4,0,0] out of it. I realize there are a few posts that are similar to this already but haven't really been able to find a fix or think of one yet. Suggestions appreciated!!

Thanks :)

Comment: can you show the code that you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
const initArr = [2,-4,5,7];
const noNegative = initArr.map(value => {
    return value < 0 ? 0 : value;
});
const absolutes = initArr.map(value => {
    return value < 0 ? Math.abs(value) : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function which returns array of arrays. The input of a function will take an array. Inside that function you can create 2 arrays. In posArray you can copy positive num from inputArray and in negArray you can copy negative numbers from inputArray. Assign it to resArray ={posArray, negArray}. Return resArray.